# If you possible http iframe run in https websites?

Tags: php, jquery, html

My iframe src is HTTP but my website run https that's iframe is not run, an error is shown: Mixed Content: The page at `<URL>` was loaded over `HTTPS`, but requested an insecure stylesheet `<URL>`. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over `HTTPS`.

Comment: Simply said: No. You cannot load HTTP content over a secure connection. In other words: When the document (page) is loaded on HTTPS, all other requests initiated by the document, MUST be HTTPS. Loading HTTP content over HTTPS is against policy, besides it'll degrade the lock-icon in the address bar.

Comment: Use the Below Code: <iframe id="fre" src="http://example.com" width="100%" height="860"></iframe> and src url is work only http not https.

Comment: There could be plenty of reasons why it doesn't work on HTTPS: Is the certificate valid? Is the webserver configured to point the correct vhost? Is the iframe blocked by X-Frame-Options HTTP header? Or blocked by CORS? Check your console's output (when calling HTTPS) and see why the request fails.

Comment: Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.ekal.org/ekal-school-map.php' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://connectapp.net/dev/fts/portal/assets/js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Comment: So change your source code and prepend https://

Comment: @Dygnus Use the nelow the code: scrapedcontent.php:
<?php
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/');
echo $homepage;
?>
index.html:

<iframe src="scrapedcontent.php"></iframe> But only text is visible not map. Not possible to change http to https so please any another way to get contents https page to put https webpage.

Comment: True, because you're depending on the source code from 'example.com' to use HTTPS. An ugly solution is to replace their http:// to https://, but its source needs to support HTTPS.